# Can I change the macro that it paste the same FORMAT as the previous one?

Tags: ms-word, formatting, copy-paste

In this code I have the problem that it copies the text but it takes the format from the new document instead from the previous one. How could I change that it takes the complete format from the previous document? (Keep Source Formating K)

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="LGRS"
End If

Dim newDoc As Document
Dim src As Range
Dim pages As Range

'set src range to start at page 2
Set src = ActiveDocument.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=2)
'extend range to the end of page 7
Set pages = ActiveDocument.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=7)
src.End = pages.GoTo(what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").End
Set newDoc = Documents.Add(, wdNewBlankDocument)
newDoc.Content.FormattedText = src.FormattedText
'remove extra paragraph at end
With newDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
  If Len(.Text) = 1 Then .Delete
End With
newDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
newDoc.Save

Application.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyRevisions, Password:="LGRS"

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using the FormattedText method, which replicates the character formatting and text from the specified 'src' range. Paragraph formatting is included for any paragraph marks in the 'src' range. If you're not getting the desired formatting, that should only affect the final paragraph - if you didn't include its paragraph break (e.g. because the paragraph ends on the next page). Section-level formatting (e.g. page setup, headers/footers) is only replicated if you copy the corresponding Section break(s).

Comment: My experience with "keep source formatting" is that it copies character-level formatting but not paragraph style formatting for styles already in use. For styles already in use, even if the formatting is in a paragraph style in the source document, you get the destination copy in the normal style with direct formatting to match the source.

Comment: So, is there a way to solve the issue with this code or do I need to work with another?